# Using Supersleight plugin creates border and broken image X mark in IE6

Tags: transparency, internet-explorer-6

I've already asked this question on the guy's blog who created this plugin but not gotten an answer yet.

I am using the supersleight.plugin.js plugin to sort out the transparency issue in IE6. It's working just great but I seem to have an issue if I have an image AND a background image which are both transparent PNG24 images in that it creates a border around the image and the little red cross which you would normally get when you open a site with broken images in IE6

Here's the link to see what I mean.

http://bit.ly/crCY2a

You'd have to view this in IE Tester for IE6

Anyone, know of a work around for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The script is looking for an image called x.gif (which comes with the JavaScript file) at the root of your web application. Either copy this image to the root or update the supersleight JS file accordingly.